# popup blocker is blocking popup while clicking on silverlight button or hyperlinkbutton

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser, cross-browser, popup

In my ViewModel I am preparing dynamic url and then calling it as follow.

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(URL), "_blank");
```

but It didn't work so I tried to call javascript from silverlight and inside javascript I called window.open() method. Code is like this:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("open_win", URL);
```

and Javascript function open_win is like this:

```
function open_win(param1) {
        var win = window.open(param1, 'ad', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes')
        win.focus();
    }
```

But it work for IE only all other browsers shows popup blocker.

I have tried one more solution to get rid of popup blocker
I have created dummy html button and triggered its click inside open_win function then also it didn't work but when I click on html button It works fine. so please help me out to do same with silverlight button.

If you have any other solution to open new browser window without popup blocker then also suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it the point of popup blockers to block popups? In my view, everything is working as expected... except IE, which fails.

Comment: I agree. Unless IE knows of Silverlight's click event, it should block the new window's creation.

Comment: @nvoigt The same is working with aspx page. When we click button on aspx page popup blocker does not block popup but when we do same with silverlight it blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the Click event in Javascript.

If you use Silverlight to receive the click, the browser doesn't know a click happened. It just assumes your code is trying to open a new browser. That is why your new window is being classified as a popup.

Use Javascript to listen for the DOM click event. Then browsers will respect your new window.